# How to get proper data using LINQ Lambda expression with many to many relation

Tags: c#, linq

Looks like a very simple case, but I can't find a proper lambda expression for it in my head or in stackoverflow :( I appreciate all help.

Case looks simple. I have two classes and relation many to many between them.

```
public class Student
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<Document> Documents { get; set; }
    }

    public class Document
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
    }
```

Then I initiate some values:

```
        Student st1 = new Student { Id = 1, Name = "Student 1" };
        Student st2 = new Student { Id = 2, Name = "Student 2" };
        Student st3 = new Student { Id = 3, Name = "Student 3" };

        List<Student> listStudent12 = new List<Student>(); 
        listStudent12.Add(st1); 
        listStudent12.Add(st2);

        List<Student> listStudent23 = new List<Student>();
        listStudent23.Add(st2); 
        listStudent23.Add(st3);


        Document doc1 = new Document { Id = 1, Name = "doc 1", Students = listStudent12 };
        Document doc2 = new Document { Id = 2, Name = "doc 2", Students = listStudent23 };

        List<Document> listDocs = new List<Document>();
        listDocs.Add(doc1);
        listDocs.Add(doc2);
```

Now I would like to get a list of documents using linq lambda expression, which are related to "Student 3" (id: 3).

I tried like this:

```
var result = listDocs.Where(d => d.Students.FirstOrDefault().Id == 3).ToList();
```

but it returns null (I guess I know why - the first returned student is not equal to 3).

I expect the result to contain all documents which has in list of students student with Id = 3. 
I stucked here and need a help. Thank you in advance for any.

On the SQL level I would go:

```
SELECT Document.* from Document, DocumentStudent WHERE Document.Id = DocumentStudent.DocumentId AND DocumentStudent.StudentId = 3
```

Comment: try var result = listDocs.Where(d => d.Students.any(s=>s.Id == 3)).ToList();

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what was needed. Thank you Ashiquizzaman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did in your example was finding any `Document` that has first `Student` with `Id: 3`. That ends up with none.

What you want to do is:

```
var result = listDocs.Where(doc => doc.Students.Any(st => st.Id == 3).ToList();
```

It will evaluate to any `Document` that has at least one `Student` with `Id: 3`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I needed. Dzięki śliczne.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will look simpler if you use the following syntax

```
var result = (from doc in listDocs
              from student in doc.Students
              where student.Id == 3
              select doc).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you that works also, however I was really wondering how it can be achived by Lambda expression, and mwilczynski answer did the job perfectly. Thank you for your help as well!